# Assigning stats in a game

Tags: c++, game

I made a program that allows you to assign stats. However it uses some fairly complex if-else statements. Also, someone told me that `goto` statements were bad, but why is that? I know that switch might have been a better solution, but I cannot get `switch` statements to work for string variables.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    int strength,agility,perception,endurance,intelligence,rem_statpoints;
    cout << "Please distribute you stat points" << endl;
    cout << "Avaivable stat points: 10 \n" << endl;
statreset:{}
          strength = 5;               //Strength     is set to 5 by default
          agility = 5;                //Agility      is set to 5 by default
          perception = 5;             //Perception   is set to 5 by default
          endurance = 5;              //Endurance    is set to 5 by default
          intelligence = 5;           //Intelligence is set to 5 by default
          rem_statpoints = 10;        //The avaivable number of stat points
stat:{}
     cout << "Strength       " << strength << endl;
     cout << "Agility        " << agility << endl;
     cout << "Perception     " << perception << endl;
     cout << "Endurance      " << endurance << endl;
     cout << "Intelligence   " << intelligence << "\n" << endl;
     cout << "What stat do you want to increase?" << endl;
     string inc;
     cin >> inc;
     if (inc == "strength" or "agility" or "perception" or "endurance" or "intelligence") {
         goto increase;
     } else {
         cout << "Please enter a valid stat, also remember to type in lower case letters" << endl;
         goto stat;
     }   
increase:{}
         cout << "How much do you want to increase " << inc << " with?" << endl;
         cout << "avaivable skill points: " << rem_statpoints << endl;
         int ass_statpoints;
         cin >> ass_statpoints;
         if (ass_statpoints > rem_statpoints) {
             cout << "Insufficient stat points" << endl;
             goto stat;
         } else {
             if (inc == "strength") {
                 strength = strength + ass_statpoints;
                 rem_statpoints = rem_statpoints - ass_statpoints;
             } else {
                 if (inc == "agility") {
                     agility = agility + ass_statpoints;
                     rem_statpoints = rem_statpoints - ass_statpoints;
                 } else {
                     if (inc == "perception") {
                         perception = perception + ass_statpoints;
                         rem_statpoints = rem_statpoints - ass_statpoints;
                     } else {
                         if (inc == "endurance") {
                             endurance = endurance + ass_statpoints;
                             rem_statpoints = rem_statpoints - ass_statpoints;
                         } else {
                             intelligence = intelligence + ass_statpoints;
                             rem_statpoints = rem_statpoints - ass_statpoints;
                         }   
                     }   
                 }   
             }   
         }
         cout << "Increased " << inc << " with " << ass_statpoints  << "\n" << endl;
red:{}
    if (rem_statpoints == 0) {
        cout << "You have distributed all your stat points, are you happy with your selection?" << endl;
        cout << "If you're not, you can redistribute them by typing unhappy" << endl;
        cout << "To start playing, simply type play!" << endl;
    } else {
        goto stat;
    }
    string red;
    cin >> red;
    string statreset;       //string statreset is placed here because I could not place it next to the relevant cin for some reason.
    if (red == "play!") {
        goto game;
    } else {
        cout << "Are you sure you want to reset your stat points?" << endl;
        cin >> statreset;   //string statreset is placed here
        if (statreset == "yes") {
            cout << "Resetting stats" << endl;
            goto statreset;
        } else {
            cout << "Do you want to start playing then?" << endl;
            string statresetno;
            cin >> statresetno;
            if (statresetno == "yes") {
                goto game;
            } else {
                cout << "Make up you mind!" << endl;
                goto red;
            }
        }
    }
    goto stat;

game:{}
     {
         cout << "Initializing game" << endl;
         cout << "game coming soon!" << endl;
         cout << "Thank you for playing!" << endl;
     }
     return 0;
}



/* Some one told me once that is was bad to use alot of goto statements,
 * however, I can not see what damage they are causing here.
 * Then again, I am not familiar with any alternatives for goto and labels,
 * so I am forced to use goto!
 * I really hoped you enjoyed using my program, and if this program for
 * some reason helped someone else, I am glad.
 * Feel free to use this code for yourself if you really found it that
 * good
 *
 *
 * Happy Trails!
 * - Lemonizer
 */
```

Comment: Please copy/paste your code into the question as per the FAQ. Otherwise, we'll be forced to close your question.

Comment: Using goto is [this bad](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/goto.png). Further reading on it, [head over to SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/52307)

Comment: I'm not sure about this case, but it's usually recommended that you use functions instead of `goto` statements.

Comment: Learn to format your code. Websites don;t like tabs so remove them before posting.

Comment: Yes. goto in this context is very bad. It makes the code really hard to read. Break this into functions. The above was re-formatted with a real cod eeditor `vim`. Sequence `<ctrl-v>0G=` redoes indent correctly. `:% s/^/    /g` adds 4 space to the front of each line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please put one variable per line:

```
    int strength,agility,perception,endurance,intelligence,rem_statpoints;
```

That is really hard to read:
It would be even better to wrap this in a structure (one day you may have 2 players at the same time).

```
struct Player
{
    int strength;
    int agility;
    int perception;
    int endurance;
    int intelligence;
};
int rem_statpoints; // not part of a player.
                    // as it is just used during player creation
```

Would it not be easier to make this a function/method:

```
statreset:{}
          strength = 5;               //Strength     is set to 5 by default
          agility = 5;                //Agility      is set to 5 by default
          perception = 5;             //Perception   is set to 5 by default
          endurance = 5;              //Endurance    is set to 5 by default
          intelligence = 5;           //Intelligence is set to 5 by default
          rem_statpoints = 10;        //The avaivable number of stat points

void Player::statreset(int& rem_statpoints)
{
          strength = 5;               //Strength     is set to 5 by default
          agility = 5;                //Agility      is set to 5 by default
          perception = 5;             //Perception   is set to 5 by default
          endurance = 5;              //Endurance    is set to 5 by default
          intelligence = 5;           //Intelligence is set to 5 by default
          rem_statpoints = 10;        //The avaivable number of stat points
}
```

This looks like another mehtod to me:

```
stat:{}
     cout << "Strength       " << strength << endl;
     cout << "Agility        " << agility << endl;
     cout << "Perception     " << perception << endl;
     cout << "Endurance      " << endurance << endl;
     cout << "Intelligence   " << intelligence << "\n" << endl;
     cout << "What stat do you want to increase?" << endl;
```

This is not doing what you think it is doing.
I am surprised if this even works as it should always return true.

```
     string inc;
     cin >> inc;
     if (inc == "strength" or "agility" or "perception" or "endurance" or "intelligence")

     // what you really want is:
     if (inc == "strength" || inc == "agility" || inc == "perception" ... etc
```

The comment at the end:

```
/* Some one told me once that is was bad to use alot of goto statements,
 * however, I can not see what damage they are causing here.
```

I can.
You are tightly binding your control flow logic.
This makes it hard to introduce new steps or alter the logic.
Following the logic in this code is even worse. It is the perfect example of spaghetti. If it works fine then great. But try following the logic when something breaks. This becomes a maintenance nightmare.

```
 * Then again, I am not familiar with any alternatives for goto and labels,
 * so I am forced to use goto!
```

Alternatives:
Combine the following:

```
 if (<test>) {<code>} else {<code>}
 for(<init>;<test>;<upd>) {<code>}
 while(<test>) {<code>}
 do {<code>} while(<test>)

 <function name>(<Parameter list>)
```

You can reduce the complexity of you of tree like this:

```
 if (<cond1>)
 {
 }
 else if (<cond2>)
 {
 }
 else if (<cond3>)
 {
 }
 else if (<cond4>)
 {
 }
 // ...etc
 else
 {
 }
```

I would restructure the code like this:

```
 int main()
 {
     Player  player1;
     do
     {
         generatePlayer(player1);
     }
     while(!isUserSatisfied());

     playGame();
 }
```

Then generatePlayer()

```
 void generatePlayer(Player& player)
 {
     int extraPoints;

     player.statreset(extraPoints);
     while(extraPoints > 0)
     {
         std::cout << player;

         std::string inc;
         int         amount;
         do
         {
             std::cout << "Attribute you want to modify?\n";
             std::cin >> inc;
         }
         while(!isValidAttribute(inc));

         do
         {
              std::cout << "You have " << extraPoints << " to play with\n";
              std::cin >> amount;
         }
         while(amount > extraPoints);

         player.modifyAttribute(inc, amount);
     }
}
```

Comment: Holy Moly. Did not expect such a thorough answer! Thank you! I will follow this to the last line, and try to do as you suggest!

Answer (score 6):

You would have to refactor this a few times to make it perfect, these are my suggestions for starters.

- Naming your variables a,b,c,d,e,s is bad form. You could have called them strength, agility, endurance, etc.
- One way to avoid your long if statement is using a 'stat' array instead of having separate variables. This way you could ask the user which stat to increase

  - 1) Strength
  - 2) Dexterity
  - 3) Strength
    etc.

The entered numbered minus 1 would be the stat to enhance. Also typing a number is funner than typing stat names.

- Finally, google 'functions' and instead of using labels, create functions and call those.

T.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't store my stats as hard-coded variables. You could store your stats inside of a map like this:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Player
{
public:
    Player()
        : m_StatPoints(10)
    {}

    int getStat(const std::string& statName) const
    {
        std::map<std::string, int>::const_iterator stat = m_Stats.find(statName);

        if (stat == m_Stats.end())
        {
            throw "exception"; //Add real exception here
        }

        return stat->second;
    }

    void addStat(const std::string& statName)
    {
        m_Stats.insert(std::make_pair(statName, 5));
    }

    void increaseStat(const std::string& statName, int points)
    {
        if (m_StatPoints - points >= 0)
        {
            m_Stats.at(statName) += points;
            m_StatPoints -= points;

            std::cout << "increased " << statName << " by " << points << " points.\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "insufficient stat points";
        }
    }

    void resetStats()
    {
        typedef std::map<std::string, int>::iterator StatIterator;

        for (StatIterator currentStat = m_Stats.begin(); currentStat != m_Stats.end(); ++currentStat)
        {
            currentStat->second = 5;
        }

        m_StatPoints = 10;
    }

private:
    std::map<std::string, int> m_Stats;
    int                        m_StatPoints;
};

int main()
{
    Player player;

    player.addStat("int");
    player.addStat("dex");
    player.addStat("str");
    player.addStat("luck");
    player.addStat("wid");

    player.increaseStat("str", 1);
    player.increaseStat("int", 4);

    std::cout << "the intelligence value of your player is: " << player.getStat("int");
    std::cout << "the strength value of your player is: "     << player.getStat("str");

    return 0;
}
```

If you store your character info inside of a map you will have it more easy to extend your character later. You could even add stats over a textfile without specificly mentioning them inside of your program first. That way you are much more felxible.

Furthermore you should use functions instead of lables since `goto` is pretty dangerous and that way your code looks very chaotic.

A function is implemented as followed:

```
returnType functionName (parameter) { what you want to do }
```

for example:

```
void printThisNumber(int number)
{
     std::cout << number;
}
```

or with a return type:

```
int getMeNumberFive()
{
    return 5;
}
```

and is called as followed:

```
printThisNumber(5);

int i = getMeNumberFive();
```

Simply google for functions, there are a lot of tutorials out there.